# How to list all Websphere installed applications for a given Middleware server using jython

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I have a Websphere 8.5.5.12 installation with multiple applications running on it. For a given Middleware Server, I'd like to be able to list all applications associated with it using Jython.

I have gone as far as writing this code:

`wsadmin>print AdminApp.list("WebSphere:cell=myCell,node=myNode")`

However this is retrieving applications for a different Dynamic Cluster

If I add a specific server, it errors out

`wsadmin>print AdminApp.list("WebSphere:cell=myCell,server=myServer")`

ADMA0184E: myServer is not a valid target.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like:

```
wsadmin>AdminApp.list("WebSphere:cell=myCell,node=myNode,server=server1")
```

It appears you're missing the node identifier in your query.  And if wsadmin still returns "myServer is not a valid target", then the server name is wrong, try looking at your app server profile directory structure to double check it.

Comment: Ok. I added the node but it's still returning the error. I checked the app server profile directory and the name is correct. I have also generated a list of all servers: AdminTask.listServers('[-serverType APPLICATION_SERVER]'). As a result I got this: myServer(cells/myCell/nodes/myNode/servers/myServer|server.xml)

Comment: Are you using dynamic app placement for the cluster?

Comment: Yes, we are using Dynamic App Placement